# add description to sharepoint folder

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

how can i add description to folder in sharepoint library ?
I added a description colonne to library , but it allows me to add description only for files and not for folders .
Any idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to create a new content type from the Site Content Types galery (link available from Site Settings). That new custom CT would inherit from the standard Folder CT.

Then, at you doc lib settings level, enable CT management (from Advanced settings) and add your custom folder CT.

In the Advanced settings page, disable the option "Create fodlers".

Now, to create a new folder, use the "New" button instead of the "Create folder" button.

Another must more suited way: use Document Sets!! There's made for that purpose. [Document Sets in SharePoint 2010 – Part 1](http://blogs.technet.com/b/vedant/archive/2010/04/21/using-the-document-set-feature-in-sharepoint-2010-part-1.aspx) and a lot other resources can be fond on the Web.

Answer (score 1):

If using SharePoint 2013 you can simplify this process - just follow these steps:

1. Create the folder (or folder structure)
2. In the Library Settings (scroll down to columns and "Create Column" and create a "Description" entry with the necessary settings tailored to your preferences (single line/multi-line, etc)
3. Ensure you adjust any views that you have, including the default, and place the Description column wherever you want to see it (note: it will show, by default, for all subfolders and documents within those folders using that view).
4. Press OK.
5. Click back on the Library tab
6. In the toolbar, click on the Quick Edit button near the left end.
7. This gives you a similar view to a datasheet, allowing you to update columns/data for each item in that given folder view.
8. Simply click on the Description field for the folder you want to provide a description and then hit enter.
9. Repeat for any additional folders (or files) including Links.
10. Click the "Stop" editing this list near the top of the list in red and you're all done (for that folder list).
11. Now just repeat this for each and every folder you create or have already created. Don't forget subfolders.

Cheers,
House

Answer (score 1):

The following link will help you :
    http://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2007/08/sharepoint-how-to-create-links-from.html

Answer (score 1):

In the Documents view:

1. In the toolbar, select 'edit in grid view'
2. You will now be able to enter the description for the folder that you want (you can edit the font and font colour as well)
3. Click the 'tick' icon to save

Comment: The "Description" cells for folders were marked as "read-only" but I added a new column and used that instead.